# Switching between LTR and RTL using styled-components?

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I'm building an English-Arabic app with next.js, and want to enable users to switch between the two languages.
I found this example from next.js: [with-styled-components-rtl](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components-rtl). It uses StylisRTLPlugin, which flips all CSS styles to fit RTL layout:

```js
    // _document.js
    <StyleSheetManager stylisPlugins={[stylisRTLPlugin]}>
      <App {...props} />
    </StyleSheetManager>
```

It works fine, but the problem is that I can't remove `stylisRTLPlugin` conditionally based on the current `locale` bacause I have no access to `useRouter()` in `_document.js`.

What I want to be able to do:

```js
    <StyleSheetManager stylisPlugins={locale === 'ar' ? [stylisRTLPlugin] : null}>
      <App {...props} />
    </StyleSheetManager>
```

Comment: I tried to use `<StyleSheetManager>` in `_app.js` instead of `_document.js` where I have access to `locale` prop, and it works fine, but I don't think this is the right way for server side rendering where styles should be served during page rendering in `_document.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this config to your `.babelrc` to force your styled to be rendered on the server.

```
  "plugins": [
    [
      "styled-components",
      {
        "ssr": true,
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: It's there, but does it mean that even if `<StyleSheetManager>` is outside `collectStyles()` in "_document.js", correct styles will be prerendered in the server?

Comment: I have no idea. But what if you just simply have a look on the fetched html code with 'view page source' (not element inspector!). If styles are ssr-d they should be visible in there.